# Visa application for housewife

Tags: visas, schengen, indian-citizens, proof-provenance-of-funds

My wife and I are applying for Schengen visas to Belgium. My wife is a housewife, and she shall be giving my bank details as proof of financial means. In that case, in the online form should she select financing by self, or financing by other?

Comment: As she is so-to-say financed by you, I'd state exactly this. However, I understood you as the bank account is your personally. If it is shared between you and your wife, it would go as self-financed. _Disclaimer:_ I am not a layer and have no idea how visa applications work.

Answer (score 1):

As she is your wife, not applying for a job (for now) in Belgium and does not have regular income she is financed by you. A shared bank account will not be considered self financed unless the amount is substantial enough (>50000 Euros) that the immigration office could assume she could life of this for 3 years in Belgium.